# Probability of picking at least k different numbers in n tries

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to refresh my knowledge in probability theory, and I got stuck on this problem.
The problem statement is,
You have a box with numbers ranged from 1..X and you pick N numbers (after you pick a number you put it back), what is the probability that you have picked at least z different numbers.

Can someone point me in the right direction.
Thanks

Comment: It's analogous to N balls going into X pipes - how many pipes are empty (or have any balls)  - saying that - I don't know it.

Comment: is this the same sort of problem?  I'm NOT saying this Q is a duplicate, but this is what I found searching the problem http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1877405/classic-10-balls-into-4-boxes-problem